# God-class which controll CNC machine

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I have a god-class (GodClass) which work with class-adapter. Class-adapter (OldController) work with old api-class which can't to use directly cause it has bad api with low-level parameters. God-class violates SRP principle. I want to split god-class but not sure of correct way to do it. In the future, some code will change in this class. How to divide it correctly for convenient further programming?

I think should create some classes which has depency injection of class-adapter as singleton. (see code example). Need help. I not sure about correct way to do it.

```
public class PmacDataService : BindableBase, ICNCControllerService
{
    //Dependency injections
    private readonly PMAC _controller = new PMAC();
    private readonly IUserSettingsService _userSettings;
    private readonly ILoggerFacade _logger;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _aggregator;

    public PmacDataService(IEventAggregator aggregator, IUserSettingsService userSettings, ILoggerFacade logger)
    {
        _userSettings = userSettings;
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.Log("Pmac loaded", Category.Debug, Priority.High);
        _aggregator = aggregator;

        _aggregator.GetEvent<MachineState>().Subscribe(MachineStateChanged);
        RegisterEventHandlers();
    }

    //Machine state changing handlers
    private void MachineStateChanged(int state)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case 0:
                OnAutoStateChanged();
                break;
            case 1:
                OnMDIStateChanged();
                break;
            case 2:
                OnManualStateChanged();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void OnAutoStateChanged()
    {

    }
    private void OnMDIStateChanged()
    {
        if (IsProgramRunning)
            AbortProgram();
    }
    private void OnManualStateChanged()
    {
        if (IsProgramRunning)
            AbortProgram();
    }

    //Event handlers
    private void RegisterEventHandlers()
    {
        OnConnect += PmacDataService_OnConnect;
        OnLostConnection += PmacDataService_OnLostConnection;
        OnError += PmacDataService_OnError;
        OnDisconnected += PmacDataService_OnDisconnected;
        OnInvalidInputFormat += PmacDataService_OnInvalidInputFormat;
    }
    private void PmacDataService_OnInvalidInputFormat(string errorMessage)
    {
        _logger.Log(errorMessage, Category.Warn, Priority.High);
    }
    private void PmacDataService_OnDisconnected()
    {
        _cancToken.Cancel();
        _logger.Log("Disconnected", Category.Warn, Priority.High);
        _aggregator.GetEvent<ConnectionEvent>().Publish(false);
    }
    private void PmacDataService_OnError(long errorCode, string errorMessage)
    {
        _logger.Log($"Code: {errorCode}. {errorMessage}", Category.Exception, Priority.High);
    }
    private void PmacDataService_OnLostConnection(long errorCode)
    {
        _cancToken.Cancel();
        _logger.Log($"Lost connection. Code {errorCode}", Category.Warn, Priority.High);
        _aggregator.GetEvent<ConnectionEvent>().Publish(false);
        IsReconnectionStarted = true;
    }
    private void PmacDataService_OnConnect()
    {
        _logger.Log("Connected to controller.", Category.Info, Priority.Medium);
        _aggregator.GetEvent<ConnectionEvent>().Publish(true);
    }


    #region Poll motors function
    private Task _motorCheck;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private int _motorCount;
    public ConcurrentObservableCollection<IMotor> Motors { get; } = new ConcurrentObservableCollection<IMotor>();
    private void DoPollMotors()
    {
        while (!_cancToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _motorCount; i++)
            {
                var motor = Motors[i];
                //Statuses
                if (_controller.GetMotorStatus(i, out PMAC.MotorStatusX statusesX, out PMAC.MotorStatusY statusesY))
                    SetMotorBits(ref motor, statusesX, statusesY);
                //Current
                if (_controller.GetMotorCurrent(i, out int phaseA, out int phaseB))
                    SetMotorCurrent(ref motor, phaseA, phaseB);
                //Position
                _controller.GetMotorPosition(i, out double position);
                motor.Position = position;
                //Letter
                if (_controller.GetResponse($"#{i + 1}->", out string motorBinding))
                {
                    string letter = string.Empty;
                    if (motorBinding.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).Count() > 0)
                        letter = new string(motorBinding.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
                    if (motor.Letter != letter)
                    {
                        motor.Letter = letter;
                        ActivatedMotorsCountChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            Task.Delay(_userSettings.Timeout).Wait();
        }
    }
    private void GetMotorsCount()
    {
        if (_controller.I7XX0[0] > 0 && _controller.I7XX0[1] > 0) //8 моторов доступно
            _motorCount = 8;
        else if (_controller.I7XX0[0] > 0 && _controller.I7XX0[1] == 0)
            _motorCount = 4;
        Motors.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < _motorCount; i++)
            Motors.Add(new Motor());
    }
    private void WhenMotorCheckingTaskIsFall(Task motorChekingTask)
    {
        _logger.Log($"Error. Motor checking task has crashed. {motorChekingTask.Exception}", Category.Exception, Priority.High);
    }
    private void SetMotorCurrent(ref IMotor motor, int phaseA, int phaseB)
    {
        motor.PhaseA = phaseA;
        motor.PhaseB = phaseB;
        motor.CurrentPercentage = (double)(Math.Abs(phaseA)) / _userSettings.MaxCurrentLimit * 100; //Calculate the percentage of the current load.
    }
    private void SetMotorBits(ref IMotor motor, PMAC.MotorStatusX statusesX, PMAC.MotorStatusY statusesY)
    {
        var activatedMotorStatus = statusesX.HasFlag(PMAC.MotorStatusX.MotorActivated);
        if (motor.Activated != activatedMotorStatus)
            ActivatedMotorsCountChanged();
        motor.Activated = activatedMotorStatus;
        motor.InPosition = statusesY.HasFlag(PMAC.MotorStatusY.InPositionTrue);
        motor.FatalFollowing = statusesY.HasFlag(PMAC.MotorStatusY.FatalFollowingErrorEx);
        motor.WarningFollowing = statusesY.HasFlag(PMAC.MotorStatusY.WarningFollowingErrorEx);
        motor.AmplifierFaultError = statusesY.HasFlag(PMAC.MotorStatusY.AmplifierFaultError);
        motor.PhasingSearchError = statusesY.HasFlag(PMAC.MotorStatusY.PhasingSearchError);
        motor.PhaseRequest = statusesY.HasFlag(PMAC.MotorStatusY.MotorPhaseRequest);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Manage connection function
    public bool Connected => _controller.Connected;
    private bool _isReconnectionStarted;
    public bool IsReconnectionStarted
    {
        get => _isReconnectionStarted;
        private set
        {
            _isReconnectionStarted = value;
            if (value == true)
                DoReconnect();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Try connect to controller
    /// </summary>
    public void Connect()
    {
        if (_userSettings.DeviceNumber == -1)
            SelectController();
        _controller.Connect(_userSettings.DeviceNumber, _userSettings.Timeout);
        GetMotorsCount();
        _cancToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _motorCheck = new Task(DoPollMotors, _cancToken.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        _motorCheck.ContinueWith(WhenMotorCheckingTaskIsFall, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        _motorCheck.Start();
    }
    private void DoReconnect()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _userSettings.ReconnectionCount; i++)
        {
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
            if (!Connected)
            {
                _logger.Log($"Try reconnect to controller #{i + 1}", Category.Info, Priority.Medium);
                Connect();
                if (Connected)
                {
                    IsReconnectionStarted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Breaks the connection to the controller.
    /// </summary>
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _cancToken.Cancel();
        _cancToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _controller.Disconnect();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invites the user to select a controller
    /// </summary>
    public bool SelectController(bool autoConnect = false)
    {
        if (!_controller.SelectController(out int deviceNumber))
            return false;
        _userSettings.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
        if (autoConnect)
        {
            if (Connected)
                Disconnect();
            Connect();
        }

        return true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Get/Set variables function
    /// <summary>
    /// Set int variable value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="variableName">Variable name.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value for the given variable.</param>
    /// <returns>The success of the operation.</returns>
    public bool SetVariable(string variableName, int value)
    {
        if (Regex.Match(variableName, @"^[IMPimp]\d+$").Success)
        {
            var result = _controller.GetResponse($"{variableName}={value}", out string response);
            if (result && response.Length == 0)
                return true;
        }
        OnInvalidInputFormat($"Invalid request format when setting a variable: {variableName}");
        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a double value for the given variable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="variableName">Variable name.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value for the given variable.</param>
    /// <returns>The success of the operation.</returns>
    public bool SetVariable(string variableName, double value)
    {
        if (Regex.Match(variableName, @"^[IMPimp]\d+$").Success)
        {
            var result = _controller.GetResponse($"{variableName}={value}", out string response);
            if (result && response.Length == 0)
                return true;
        }
        OnInvalidInputFormat($"Invalid request format when setting a variable: {variableName}");
        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Reading a variable of value of type int.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="variableName">Variable name.</param>
    /// <param name="result">Variable value.</param>
    /// <returns>The success of the operation.</returns>
    public bool GetVariable(string variableName, out int result)
    {
        result = -1;
        bool parseSuccess = false;
        if (Regex.Match(variableName, @"^[IMPimp]\d+$").Success && _controller.GetResponse($"{variableName}", out string response))
        {
            if (response.Contains("$"))
                parseSuccess = int.TryParse(response.Trim('$'), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out result);
            else
                parseSuccess = int.TryParse(response, out result);

            return parseSuccess;
        }
        OnInvalidInputFormat($"Invalid request format when reading a variable: {variableName}");
        return parseSuccess;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Reading a variable of value of type double.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="variableName">Variable name.</param>
    /// <param name="result">Variable value.</param>
    /// <returns>The success of the operation.</returns>
    public bool GetVariable(string variableName, out double result)
    {
        result = -1;
        bool parseSuccess = false;
        if (Regex.Match(variableName, @"^[IMPimp]\d+$").Success && _controller.GetResponse($"{variableName}", out string response))
        {
            if (response[0] == '$')
                parseSuccess = (double.TryParse(response.Trim('$'), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out result));
            else if (response.Contains('.'))
                parseSuccess = double.TryParse(response, out result);
            return parseSuccess;
        }
        OnInvalidInputFormat($"Invalid request format when reading a variable: {variableName}");
        return parseSuccess;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Jog functions
    public void TryJog(string axis, bool negativeDirection, int velocityFactor = 1)
    {
        var motors = Motors.Where(m => m.Activated && string.Compare(m.Letter, axis) == 0);
        string direction = negativeDirection ? "-" : "+";
        string command = "";
        foreach (var motor in motors)
        {
            command += $"#{Motors.IndexOf(motor) + 1}J{direction} ";
            RememberOldFeedrateVelocity(Motors.IndexOf(motor) + 1);
            SetVariable($"I{Motors.IndexOf(motor) + 1}22", 20 * velocityFactor);
        }
        _controller.GetResponse(command, out _);
    }
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> _oldFeedrateVelocity = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    private void RememberOldFeedrateVelocity(int motorNumber)
    {
        GetVariable($"I{motorNumber}22", out int oldVelocity);
        _oldFeedrateVelocity.Add(motorNumber, oldVelocity);
    }
    private void RestoreOldFeedrateVelocity()
    {
        foreach (var motor in _oldFeedrateVelocity)
        {
            SetVariable($"I{motor.Key}22", motor.Value);
        }
        _oldFeedrateVelocity.Clear();
    }
    public void StopJog()
    {
        _controller.GetResponse("K", out _);
        RestoreOldFeedrateVelocity();
    }
    public void JogIncrementally(string axis, int stepLength, bool negativeDirection, int velocityFactor = 1)
    {
        var motors = Motors.Where(m => m.Activated && string.Compare(m.Letter, axis) == 0);
        string direction = negativeDirection ? "-" : "+";
        string command = "";
        foreach (var motor in motors)
        {
            command += $"#{Motors.IndexOf(motor) + 1}J:{direction}{stepLength} ";
        }
        _controller.GetResponse(command, out _);
    }
    #endregion

    # region Program load function
    public bool IsProgramRunning
    {
        get => _isProgramRunning;
        private set => SetProperty(ref _isProgramRunning, value);
    }
    private bool _isProgramPaused;
    public bool IsProgramPaused
    {
        get => _isProgramPaused;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isProgramPaused, value);
    }
    private bool _isProgramRunning;
    private int _ProgramStringNumber;
    public int ProgramStringNumber
    {
        get => _ProgramStringNumber;
        private set => SetProperty(ref _ProgramStringNumber, value);
    }
    public int CoordinateSystemNumber { get; set; }
    public int MachineType
    {
        get => _userSettings.MachineType;
        set => _userSettings.MachineType = value;
    }
    private Task _rotBufLoader;
    private CancellationTokenSource _rotBufCancToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private NCFile _programFile;
    private CancellationTokenSource _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> LoadedProgram { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

    public async Task<string[]> OpenProgramFile(string programPath)
    {
        if (_programFile != null)
            _programFile.Dispose();

        LoadedProgram.Clear();
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _programFile = new NCFile(programPath, false);
            return _programFile.GetSomeString(0, _programFile.StringCount > 10 ? 10 : _programFile.StringCount).Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');
        }).ConfigureAwait(true);
    }
    private void DoRotLoad()
    {
        IsProgramRunning = true;
        int currentString = 0;
        int loadedString;
        Guard.Against.Null(_programFile, nameof(_programFile));
        // Initial load N number of rows
        for (loadedString = 0; loadedString < 300 && loadedString < _programFile.StringCount; loadedString++)
        {
            string sourceString = _programFile.GetClearSomeString(loadedString, 1);
            LoadedProgram.AddOrUpdate(loadedString + 1, $"N{loadedString + 1} {sourceString}", (key, val) => $"N{loadedString + 1} {sourceString}");
            var tempStr = ApplyOffsets($"M920=={loadedString + 1}M921={loadedString + 1}{sourceString}", CoordinateSystemNumber, GetTCode(sourceString) ?? 0, MachineType);
            _controller.RotBufSendString(tempStr, 0);
        }
        // Run the program
        _controller.GetResponse("J/ R", out _);
        // Start polling the current line number
        if (_programStringNumberCheckerCancToken != null)
            _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken.Cancel();
        _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(DoCheckProgramStringNumber, _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken.Token);
        //Reload lines to buffer
        while (loadedString < _programFile.StringCount)
        {
            GetVariable("M920", out currentString);
            while ((loadedString - currentString) < 30)
            {
                GetVariable("M920", out currentString);
                if (loadedString == _programFile.StringCount)  // The program has ended
                {
                    _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken.Cancel();
                    IsProgramRunning = false;
                    return;
                }
                string sourceString = _programFile.GetClearSomeString(loadedString, 1);
                LoadedProgram.AddOrUpdate(loadedString + 1, $"N{loadedString + 1} {sourceString}", (key, val) => $"N{loadedString + 1} {sourceString}");
                var tempStr = ApplyOffsets($"M920=={loadedString + 1}M921={loadedString + 1}{sourceString}", CoordinateSystemNumber, GetTCode(sourceString) ?? 0, MachineType);
                _controller.RotBufSendString(tempStr, 0);
                loadedString++;
            }
            // Check for the Abort command
            if (_rotBufCancToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                bool canceledOk = false;
                string abortResult;
                _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken.Cancel();
                do
                {
                    canceledOk = _controller.GetResponse("A K", out abortResult);
                } while (!canceledOk && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(abortResult));
                IsProgramRunning = false;
                return;
            }
            Task.Delay(500).Wait();
        }
        // All lines are loaded, expect when all remaining lines are processed or the Abort command is called
        while (currentString != loadedString)
        {
            GetVariable("M920", out currentString);
            if (_rotBufCancToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                bool canceledOk = false;
                string abortResult;
                _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken.Cancel();
                do
                {
                    canceledOk = _controller.GetResponse("A K", out abortResult);
                } while (!canceledOk && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(abortResult));
                break;
            }
            Task.Delay(500).Wait();
        }
        IsProgramRunning = false;
        _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken.Cancel();
    }
    private void DoCheckProgramStringNumber()
    {
        while (!_programStringNumberCheckerCancToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            GetVariable("M920", out int num);
            ProgramStringNumber = num;
            Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies offset to the program line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="programString">Program string.</param>
    /// <param name="coordinateSystem">Number of coordinate system.</param>
    /// <param name="toolNumber">Tool number</param>
    /// <param name="machineType">Machine type</param>
    /// <returns>Program line with recalculated coordinates.</returns>
    public string ApplyOffsets(string programString, int coordinateSystem, int toolNumber, int machineType) =>
            MachineOffsetCalculator.ApplyOffsets(programString, coordinateSystem, toolNumber, (MachineType)machineType, _userSettings);
    public void ResetProgram()
    {
        _aggregator.GetEvent<ResetEvent>().Publish();
        _controller.GetResponse("A K", out _);
        if (IsProgramRunning)
            AbortProgram();
        _programFile?.Dispose();
        IsProgramPaused = false;
    }
    public void StartProgram(int line = 0)
    {
        if (!_controller.Connected)
            return;

        if (_controller.DPRAvailable())
        {
            _controller.GetResponse("A", out _);
            SetVariable("M920", 0);
            SetVariable("M921", 0);
            _controller.GetResponse("DELETE LOOKAHEAD", out _);
            _controller.GetResponse("DELETE ROT", out _);
            _controller.GetResponse("DELETE GATHER", out _);
            _controller.RotBufRemove(0);
            _controller.GetResponse("&1 DEFINE ROT 4096", out _);
            _controller.GetResponse("&1 DEFINE LOOKAHEAD 500,5", out _);
            _controller.RotBufClear(0);
            Task.Delay(1000);
            _controller.RotBufSet(true);

            if (_rotBufLoader != null)
                _rotBufLoader.Dispose();
            if (_rotBufCancToken != null)
                _rotBufCancToken.Cancel();
            _rotBufCancToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _rotBufLoader = new Task(() => DoRotLoad(), _rotBufCancToken.Token);
            _rotBufLoader.ContinueWith(WhenRotaryBufferLoadingTaskIsFall, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            _rotBufLoader.Start();
        }
    }
    private void WhenRotaryBufferLoadingTaskIsFall(Task task)
    {
        _rotBufCancToken.Cancel();
        _programStringNumberCheckerCancToken.Cancel();
        IsProgramRunning = false;
        foreach (var item in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
        {
            _logger.Log($"Exception: {item.GetType().Name} Message: {item.Message}. Stack: {item.StackTrace}", Category.Exception, Priority.High);
        }

    }
    public void AbortProgram()
    {
        _rotBufCancToken.Cancel();
    }
    public void PauseProgram()
    {
        var result = _controller.GetResponse("Q", out string res);
        if (result)
            IsProgramPaused = true;
        if (!result || res.ToUpper().Contains("ERR"))
            _logger.Log("Pausing error", Category.Warn, Priority.High);
    }
    public void ResumeProgram()
    {
        if (!IsProgramPaused)
            return;
        _controller.GetResponse("R", out _);
        IsProgramPaused = false;
    }
    public string[] GetProgramString(int stringNumber, int count = 1)
    {
        return _programFile.GetSomeString(stringNumber, count).Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');
    }
    #endregion

    #region Calculate codes function
    public void GetGCodes(string programString, Dictionary<int, double?> gGroups)
    {
        CodeProcessor.GetGCodes(programString, gGroups);
    }
    public void GetMCodes(string programString, Dictionary<int, int?> mGroup)
    {
        CodeProcessor.GetMCodes(programString, mGroup);
    }
    public int GetGGroup(double gCode)
    {
        return CodeProcessor.GetGCodeGroup(gCode);
    }
    public int GetMGroup(int mCode)
    {
        return CodeProcessor.GetMCodeGroup(mCode);
    }
    public int? GetTCode(string programString)
    {
        return CodeProcessor.GetTCode(programString);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Terminal client function
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends command to controller terminal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">The command to send.</param>
    /// <param name="answer">The success of the operation.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool TerminalResponse(string query, out string answer)
    {
        return _controller.GetResponse(query, out answer);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event Action OnConnect
    {
        add { _controller.OnConnect += value; }
        remove { _controller.OnConnect -= value; }
    }
    public event Action<long, string> OnError
    {
        add { _controller.OnError += value; }
        remove { _controller.OnError -= value; }
    }
    public event Action OnDisconnected
    {
        add { _controller.OnDisconnected += value; }
        remove { _controller.OnDisconnected -= value; }
    }
    public event Action<long> OnLostConnection
    {
        add { _controller.OnLostConnection += value; }
        remove { _controller.OnLostConnection -= value; }
    }
    public event Action ActivatedMotorsCountChanged = delegate { };
    public event Action<string> OnInvalidInputFormat = delegate { };
    #endregion
}
```

Is this variant of refactoring correct?

*It's an abstract solution.*

````
class ControllerConnectionManager : IControllerConnectionManager
{
    OldController _controller;
    public ControllerManager(OldController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }
    public bool Connected => _controller.Connected;
    public bool IsReconnectionStarted { get; set; }

    public event Action OnConnect;
    public event Action OnDisconnected;
    public event Action<long> OnLostConnection;
    public event Action<long, string> OnError;

    public void Connect();
    public bool SelectController(bool autoConnect = false);
    public void Disconnect();
}

class ControllerInformationService : IControllerInformation
{
    OldController _controller;
    public ControllerManager(OldController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
        if (_controller.Connected)
            Task.Run(() => StartMotorsPolling());
    }
    public ConcurrentObservableCollection<IMotor> Motors { get; set; }

    private void StartMotorsPolling();
}

class ManualMovementManager : IManualMovementManager
{
    OldController _controller;
    public ManualMovementManager(OldController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }
    public void TryJog(string axis, bool negativeDirection, int velocityFactor = 1);
    public void StopJog();
    public void JogIncrementally(string axis, int stepLength, bool negativeDirection, int velocityFactor = 1);

    public event Action<long, string> OnError;
}

class ControllerProgramManager : IControllerProgramManager
{
    OldController _controller;
    public ControllerProgramManager(OldController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }

    public int CoordinateSystemNumber { get; set; }
    public int MachineType { get; set; }
    public ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> LoadedProgram { get; set; }
    public int ProgramStringNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsProgramRunned { get; set; }
    public bool IsProgramPaused { get; set; }

    public Task<string[]> OpenProgramFile(string programPath);
    public void StartProgram(int line = 0);
    public void PauseProgram();
    public void ResumeProgram();
    public void AbortProgram();
    public void ResetProgram();
    public string[] GetProgramStrings(int strNumber, int count = 1);


    public event Action<long, string> OnError;
}

class CodeCalculator : ICodeCalculator
{
    public static void GetGCodes(string progStr, Dictionary<int, double?> gGroups);
    public static int GetGGroup(double gcode);
    public static void GetMCodes(string progStr, Dictionary<int, int?> mGroup);
    public static int GetMGroup(int mcode);
    public static int? GetTCode(string progStr);

    public event Action<long, string> OnError;
}

class ControllerTerminalManager : IControllerTerminalManager
{
    OldController _controller;
    public ControllerTerminalManager(OldController controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }
    public bool TerminalResponse(string query, out string answer);

    public event Action<string> OnInvalidInputFormat;
    public event Action<long, string> OnError;
}
```
````

Comment: @Heslacher thank you very much. I was advised at stack to transfer my question here.

Comment: @Heslacher ok. I added full body of code.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you told us what the code does, what is the application? I see the word `motor` in the class, is this an automotive solution?

Comment: @pacmaninbw no. It's a cnc machine. Universal program for laser, turning, milling machines. This class works with cnc macnines.